# Cannot write network share

Tags: networking, windows-7, smb

I'm trying to set up my personal computer to access my work file shares. I mounted successfully and I can read files just fine, but I have no write access.
Here is the line I added to my fstab:

```
//srvfi/Tests /media/Tests cifs username=dbrown,password=******,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

What do I add?

Usually, this share is automatically added to my account on the Windows 7 of the work computer. I just log into the server with the same information as my Windows log-in.

Comment: Okay, I can mark this as solved now. After many failed chown's, I realized I should just append the line with file_mode and dir_mode arguments. Working just fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer here so that I can mark it as solved. Everything worked after I added `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` to the mount line. `chown` just gave me permission denied errors.

Comment: Also see http://www.john-am.com/2011/11/changing-ownership-on-a-linux-cifs-share/